# Вконтакте игнорирует подпись приложения (авторизация на Android)

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишем приложение под Android, которое авторизируется через контанкт согласно документации: https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk. Что удивительно - все работает, при чем работает даже без указания имени приложения (com.android.testXXX) и подписи сертификата. То есть для авторизации через контакт достаточно только идентификатора приложения (которое обычное число) и получается я могу себя залогинить вообще в любое приложение, угадав его номер. Кто сталкивался? Может я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: Под кем логинитесь? Если под тем же кто разработчик - то так и должно быть.

Comment: @SergeMarkov попробовал через другой аккаунт - тоже самое, логинится без всяких проблем